# Issue related to Reusable Action in QTP

Tags: qtp

I have made a login Action and made it reusable.I use this in 3 other scripts..
But what's going on is that if i change user name in that reuseable action's local table,it is not getting updated in other scripts.
Other script use old username.But if i call copy of this reusable action again in those 3 scripts then it takes new username..But i donn want to call again and again this reusable action after changing data in it...for it what to do???:(

Can anybody help me in it...

Thank u so much

Comment: How do you reference the user name from the local table? DataTable ("bla",dtLocalSheet)? Then think about what is the local sheet in each situation. And where do you WANT the username to be stored -- in the caller's local table? In the reusable action's local table?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're doing is you're calling the copy of action (Call to copy of action) that makes the changes in local copy only. 
You should call the existing action (Call to Existing action) to get the changes reflected everywhere if you make any changes in original action.

Thanks,
GD